# Programmatically indent auto-generated C code

Tags: python

I have a python script that auto generates C code.
Here is a small snippet:

```
source = open("auto_comps.c", "w")    
filter_proto = """bool filter_%s_%s(char *record, 
                  size_t field_offset, 
                  uint64_t value, 
                  uint64_t delta)"""
...
for op in 'eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'le', 'ge':
    for atype in 'uint8_t', 'uint16_t', 'uint32_t', 'uint64_t':
        source.write(filter_proto%(op,atype))
```

I would NOT like to explicitly create indents for the C code in the script.
Currently I let the script generate the code with haywire indentation
and later use the IDE to select the whole code and indent it from there.

However, as a result I have to manually do this process every time I have to 
tweak the script. In addition, another developer may not have the luxury of having
an IDE and may go crazy looking at the auto-generated C code.

Is there a way I can programmatically indent the code from the script just 
before I close the source file?

Comment: Add a postprocessing step with an indention tool of your choice. I do not know which one is good and support your indention style.

Comment: For something this simple, it seems that you could make filter_proto write out properly indented code, or is your actual use much more complicated than what is shown here?

Comment: @knivil, a quick google search turned up this: http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/ and https://sourceforge.net/projects/uncrustify/

Answer (score 7):

Indentation of source code is much more complex than it first appears. In fact, to indent source code properly, you will need to effectively build the front-end to a compiler. Have a look at [this article](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.co.uk/2007/06/rich-programmer-food.html) for an idiosyncratic view of this.

The point is, you really, really want to be using a tool that someone else has created. Here are some:

- [Astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/)
- [BCpp](http://invisible-island.net/bcpp/bcpp.html)
- [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/)
- Good old [indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_(Unix)))

Out of those, I have personal experience with AsStyle in C and Java and would happily recommend it.

Comment: If you are looking for python dependencies here it is. https://pypi.org/project/astyle-py/#description

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably to run the generated code through a standalone indenter such as [GNU indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/).

Answer (score 0):

BTW, reindenting may require you to recognize the c tokens and act upon it. You may probably start with [reindent.py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Reindent/0.1.0) which is for python, but change the tokens to C. I think, it may at least make you realize the difficulty of the task!. :)

The other option is to install a program like [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) and run your generated code through that, before writing to the file. That would be easier.